# How do I loop through displaying blob images from my database?

Tags: php, sql, image, loops, blob

Just to declare first that i have already been advised that this is not the best way to store and display images but I have been tasked to do it this way so any help would be greatly appreciated (The better way being storing the file paths in the database etc).

After a great deal of time spent searching the web I think I have found out that the best way to solve  my particular problem is to use a separate file to decode the blob and the link it into the file that you want to display the image on. Something to do with not being able to have more than one different type of header per page.

Any help would be great as you can probably tell i'm not good with PHP at all.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("***","***","*****");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("learning_game", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
?>
<head>
<title>Game Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Game Data Input</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a table called 'data' and the blob file is under a column called 'image'

Ideally I would like to loop through all the blobs in the database and print them in browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you for any replies in advance.

Comment: The only way to do this is, to print multiple `<img src="image.php?id=imageid" />` on your page, where imageid is the primary key in your table. And make a separate file image.php, which looks up the particular row and sends the image data. There is no way you can send both HTML and image data back in one request, as you have to specify the 'content type'.

Comment: @TarandeepGill Actually there is provided that the browser supports data uri's. It will add some weight to the page as every image has to be base 64 encoded.

Comment: Please don't do it that way. Your pages will be really really heavy. But if you really wanna do it, let me know. I will write up an example for you.

Comment: @TarandeepGill that would be great thank you. I have no idea what to put in the image.php file so an example of the whole process would be great. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Sammitch's example below is pretty much what I would have written. If you can't understand it, that means your PHP skills are really low. I would recommend spending a couple of hours on some basic PHP tutorials/lessons. Trust me it would be worth the while.

Comment: I do understand Sammitch's code, it just it does not work for me at the moment. I also do not know how to make it work when I want to loop through it printing all my images on the page

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
printf('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,%s">', base64_encode($myblobdata));
```

Which will give you something like:

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,Cldhcm5...pbmUgNQo='>
```

Except much longer.

Like everyone is saying the comments, this will make your page "heavy". If these are anything larger than simple icons a few pixels across you should seriously consider using a separate script to serve them as images. ie:

```
<?php
$myblob = your_code_here();
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $myblob;
exit;
```

Comment: in the ($myblobdata)); would that be a variable e.g $myblobdata = $row['image']; or would could you simply just insert the value straight from the database e.g. $row['image']?

Comment: I have tried your code, it seems i'm not getting anything outputted from the database so i'm trying to remedy that at the movement